# How can I get a Jackson to ignore a key that failed to deserialize with a custom KeyDeserializer?

Tags: java, jackson

I'm deserializing a Map with Jackson using a custom key deserializer that transforms the key before using it. I'd like to avoid null keys, so I'm trying to configure Jackson to just discard that entry and keep going, but I can't seem to find the right annotation. I annotating my `map` property with `@JsonInclude`, `@JsonIgnoreProperties`, and `@JsonFilter` with no luck.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{ \"map\": { \"0\": \"zero\", \"1\": \"one\" } }", Test.class).map); // Works
System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{ \"map\": { \"0\": \"zero\", \"one\": \"one\" } }", Test.class).map); // Fails
```

Here's the class I'm deserializing:

```
public class Test {
    @JsonDeserialize(keyUsing = StringIntKeyDeserializer.class, contentAs = String.class)
    public Map<Integer, String> map;
}
```

And my KeyDeserializer

```
public class StringIntKeyDeserializer extends KeyDeserializer {
    @Override
    public Object deserializeKey(String key, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(key);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw ctxt.weirdKeyException(Integer.class, key, e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `StringIntKeyDeserializer`, Instead of throwing an exception, return null

Comment: I'm OK with the change, but this just leads to a null key in the Map. How would I filter it out?

Comment: I could not figure anything from Jackson (not saying its ruled out, I just could not figure one). Not sure whether creating another map from this map and in process not include null key & and its value will work for you